# Replacing double space with single space in line containing certain string

Tags: python, regex, split, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I have a large text file with rows and columns. Between all strings/data in the file, there is a double space. However, for my particular code to work, I need the double spaces to become single spaces ONLY in certain lines. These lines all start with the same string.

I've tried:

```
with open(outfile) as f3, open(outfile2,'w') as f4:
    for line in f3:
         line = line.strip()
         if "SAMPLE" in line:
             " ".join(line.split())
         if 'xyz' not in line and len(line) >=46:
             f4.write(line+'\n')
```

and I've tried:

```
import re
with open(outfile) as f3, open(outfile2,'w') as f4:
    for line in f3:
         if "SAMPLE" in line:
             re.sub("\s\s+" , " ", line)
         if 'xyz' not in line and len(line) >=46:
             f4.write(line)
```

Neither work. That second if statement to remove some lines I do not want so that cannot go away (this works as intended). However, double spacing between all data in the text file remains. How can I make it where the lines in the file containing "SAMPLE" replace double-spaces between the words in the line with single spacing?

Comment: Perhaps use `if "SAMPLE" in line: line.replace("  "," ")` (double space, single space). Right now you're splitting by a space, so the returned array has elements which are spaces at the points where there was a double space.

Comment: `re.sub("\s\s+" , " ", line)` and  `".join(line.split())` return a new string, but you don't assign it to any variable so it gets discarded immediately. Put `line =" ".join(line.split())` or `line = re.sub("\s\s+" , " ", line)` before.

Comment: None of these work. The second if-statement seems to be overriding it since it too is called "line". I need that second if-statement.

Comment: Trying the first if-statement without the second (just to see if it works at all) only writes the lines containing that "SAMPLE' string. I need all of the data in the file (including the lines not containing that string) to still write to the outfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the mutability of the strings, `" ".join(line.split())` creates a new string, that most likely is what you need, but you should assign it back to the `line` variable.

```
if "SAMPLE" in line:
    line = " ".join(line.split())
```

**Later edit:**
The second `if` is a little "strange" ... what was the intended outcome ?

```
if not line or (':' and len(line) >=46):
    f4.write(line)
```

especially the second part ... `':'` evaluates to `True` always, seems useless might be a typo or something missing.
This will write to the file only if the `line` is empty or None (evaluates to `False`) or the length of the line is `>=` 46.

The code should look like:

```
with open(outfile) as f3, open(outfile2,'w') as f4:
    for line in f3:
         line = line.strip()
         if "SAMPLE" in line:
             # we clean eventual double/multi-space if the line contains "SAMPLE"
             line = " ".join(line.split()) 
         if 'xyz' not in line and len(line) >=46:
             # write to the second file only the lines that
             # don't contain 'xyz' and have the length of the line => 46 
             f4.write(line+'\n')
```

Comment: I tried this too. It does not change anything. Its like that line of code isnt even there. Plus I still need "line" to be considered for that second if-statement.

Comment: The easiest way to debug things is to add `print` calls  "everywhere" to get a glimpse on what's happening.

Comment: I know. And it is not working. If I try it without the second if-statement, it is only writing the lines that contain that string with "SAMPLE". I need all the data to still be written.

Comment: The second if statement is just to get rid of some lines in the file which contain ":" and that length. It works fine.

Comment: That if statement does not check for ':' in the line, it should contain ```':' in line```. Please provide a sample of the input file (if it doesn't contain private data).

Comment: You said that you've removed the second `if` and you got only the lines with "SAMPLE" written in the file ... did you also decremented the indentation level of the ```f4.write(line+'\n')``` ?! I mean if you eliminate that second if this instruction should be at the same indentation level as the if  (not inside it).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s = " ".join(your_string.split())
```

Comment: But he tried that and it doesn't work, because there are `" "` in the array returned by `your_string.split()`.

Comment: @Ardweaden Pay attention to the details, he didn't do the assignment. Also `.split()` called without arguments (or with None) splits by any number of consecutive whitespaces as according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for that.

Comment: Yes I did do that but it did not work, so I didn't include in my example. I am trying to explain. the double if-statements are not isolating the lines separately.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code answers the question.